# Is there a way to embed an image directly in an Email template in Dynamics CRM 2015?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

In CRM 2015 (on premise), I know you can insert images in emails/email templates by creating an HTML page with images that are hosted on the web and copy/pasting the HTML in the email/email template. The problem I have with that is customers who use Outlook that receive the email see big X's at first and Outlook prompts them to download images.

Is there a way to embed the images directly in the email? Or a third party tool that would allow that?
 I tried converting the images to base64 and entering the code directly into the Body field in the TemplateBase table of the CRM database, but the application just converts it to the tag `<img>` with nothing else in the sent emails.

Comment: My company is seeking the same answer.  We have brought it up to our Microsoft rep.  Our application partner wasn't aware of a third-party tool, but suggested we could take the HTML approach - the problem for us is that it would require us to store the images on the web, and the images are ITAR-controlled.

Comment: The workaround we ended up using was create a web application that sends the emails (with the images base64-embedded in the html email) and creating a Workflow Activity plugin in CRM to call the web app page with the correct parameters